# Kubuntu 16.04 Konqueror always use new Window when I click on a folder

Tags: kubuntu, kde

When I click on a folder inside Konqueror File Manager a new window appears. But this doesn't fit my intended setting! And i can't set Konqueror to act as before! If I try to change Konqueror settings within the UI or inside the configuration file (`~/.kde/share/config$ cat konquerorrc`) it doesn't do anything! My `konquerorrc` has:

```
[FMSettings]
AlwaysNewWin=false
```

But this setting seems to be completely ignored. I've tried to suppress this file but I get nothing more!

I've tried to reinstall Konqueror with :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall konqueror
```

but the behavior is the same, I can't get ride of this setting!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer at the end of this post:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/konqueror-opens-multiple-times-282593/page2.html

So i let the question here since it make more chance to everybody 
to found the answer!

bye bye